# Why do inetinfo.exe, dllhost.exe and aspnet_wp.exe all start under debugger on themselves and I can't attach to either?

Tags: asp.net, debugging, iis, iis-5

I'm trying to debug an ASP.NET application. I've created a virtual directory in IIS, copied all the binaries and web.config there. When I pass request from the client program running on the same computer aspnet_wp.exe is started but then something goes wrong.

I want to attach to the process and try debug it. When I ask Visual Studio to "Attach to process" it displays a list of processes and `aspnet_wp.exe`, `inetinfo.exe` and `dllhost.exe` are all displayed grayed as if they are already debugged by some other program and so I can't attach to any of them.

I have tried to disable the "debug" option in web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="false">
    othersettings
</system.web>
```

but it didn't change the behavior.

What's happening and how do I make aspnet_wp, inetinfo and dllhost all start in such way I can attach a debugger to either of them?

Comment: In VS Application Properties have you checked option about "IIS" (Properties -> Web)? Because you don't need to attach your process to aspnet but you can automatically run you application and web server work well.

Comment: @RoBYCoNTe: I tried to uncheck "ASP.NET" in the "Debuggers" section but it didn't change the behavior. What else should I check?

Comment: In "Server Option" what is checked? I use italian version of visual studio but the label to check should be "Use IIS Web Server" and not "Use Visual Studio Development Server".

Comment: @RoBYCoNTe: Yes, it's set to "use IIS".

Comment: http://haacked.com/images/haacked_com/WindowsLiveWriter/07de283cb368_B754/01-project-properties_4.png after, try checking option "Don't open a page. Wait for a request from an external application"

Comment: @RoBYCoNTe: Did that too, no changes.

Comment: @sharptooth sorry now i've no idea about this problem :(

Comment: @RoBYCoNTe: Finally I tracked it down and got it resolved - see my answer. That was a really surprising one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by [IIS Diagnostic Toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=9bfa49bc-376b-4a54-95aa-73c9156706e7) which I installed recently. Since it performs some magic sniffering on IIS it needs attaching as a debugger. I don't know which component of the toolkit is causing the problem.

After I removed the toolkit all the three processes start normally and I can attach Visual Studio debugger to any of them.